# Linear operator and functions

Tags: functional-analysis

I am studying functional analysis and I have a question that i suspsect has a really simple answer but I can't figure it out.

What is the difference, if there is any, between linear operators and linear functions? I know that a linear operator is a mapping between two vector spaces.

If there is any difference, can you give me an example of a linear function that is not a linear operator?

Or is it that whenever we are talking about linear operators, we identify them with linear functions?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Different textbooks use different terms. Generally, "operator" is the mapping from the vector space to itself, i.e. $V \to V$. Some book may also call it "function". Other books may use "function" to refer "functional", where the latter is specifically the mapping from the space to the field underlying the space, e.g.  $V \to \mathbb C$.

Comment: I see. So that means there is no difference? And when somone talks about linear functions they might as well call them linear operators without being wrong? Sorry for silly questions i just want to be sure i understand it correctly.

Comment: Yeah, nothing different essentially. This is totally up to the choice of the author. I myself would use the terms "operator" & "functional".

Comment: Ok, thank you for the help.

Comment: A linear function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is usually understood to be of the form $f(x) = ax + b, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ for some $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$. However, such a function is in fact affine, a sum of a linear function and a constant vector, whereas true linear operators on the vector space $\mathbb{R}$ are of the form $x \mapsto \lambda x$, for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$.